# How to disable context menu in WPF?

Tags: wpf, command, binding, command-pattern

I have two Menu items in a wpf context, 
I bind them with command, how do I hide context menu when both items are not available, I mean when both commands cannot be executed?

Answer (score 14):

Add an event handler for ContextMenuOpening event. Set Handled property in ContextMenuEventArgs object to true and the context menu will not open.